# How to add touch buttons in a platform game?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, game-engine

I am developing a 2D video game for android, the only thing I need to finish is to make the touch controls. The video game only contains movement to the right and left and jump (like MarioBros). I have already created the buttons on canvas, I only need the script, I would greatly appreciate your help, I enclose my player code in case you can help me with the modifications.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float jumpPower = 15f;
    private bool jump;
    public bool grounded;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    private Animator anim;
    private GameObject healthbar;
    public GameObject panelGameOver;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

        healthbar = GameObject.Find("Healthbar");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)
        {
            jump = true;
        }
        anim.SetBool("Grounded", grounded);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                if (GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX == true)
                {
                    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
                }
                GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Correr", true);
                transform.Translate(0.1f, 0, 0);
            }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            {
                if (GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX == false)
                {
                    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
                }
                GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Correr", true);
                transform.Translate(-0.1f, 0, 0);
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            {
                GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Correr", false);
            }
            //Saltar
            if (jump)
            {
                rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                jump = false;
            }

        }






        //
    }
    public void EnemyJump()
    {
        jump = true;


    }

    public void EnemyJumpB()
    {
        healthbar.SendMessage("TakeDamage", 30);
        jump = true;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach (or you already have an attached) Button component on your UI buttons, and you can use them like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickExample : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button yourButton;

    void Start () {
        Button btn = yourButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(TaskOnClick);
    }

    void TaskOnClick(){
        Debug.Log ("You have clicked the button!");
    }
}
```

All the "if" statements you have in your Update() and FixedUpdate() scripts could be replaced with appropriate "TaskOnClick()" functions (naming them in a nice way <3) and could be subscribed to the button clicks (AddListener()).

"if"'s :

```
public Button leftButton;

private void OnLeftButton() {
    if (GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX == false) {
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
    }
    GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Correr", true);
    transform.Translate(-0.1f, 0, 0);
}

private void Awake() {
    this.leftButton.onClick.AddListener(OnLeftButton)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, how could you replace the 'if'?

Comment: Thank you, it works when I click, but it does not walk normally, even if I press and hold the key to advance it stops, I have to press it fast so that it can move forward :( as it does not recognize the coliders

Comment: @Jesus the switch a bool around from onPointerDown and OnPointerUp funcitons, then check if that bool is true in an Update() and call OnLeftButton from there